# Shell Script - SSH using Screen

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2, ssh, gnu-screen

I am trying to develop a shell script / bash script with ssh and screen, using Ubuntu / Linux.
Could you help me to correct what is wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i keypair.pem -t ubuntu@ec2-address "screen -S teste"; cd 'home'; cd 'Shell'; ./'AWS - teste.sh' "
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fell victim to shell quoting - which is tricky when using ssh. Your command does something alike

```
cd home/Shell; ./AWS - teste.sh
```

so I would try

```
ssh -i keypair.pem -t ubuntu@ec2-address screen -S teste "sh -c \"cd home/Shell; ./AWS - teste.sh\""
```